# Convertions String which has list of objects to a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a string as

```
str=[{"A":120.0,"B":"0005236"},{"A":10.0,"B":"0005200"},
{"A":12.0,"B":"00042276"},{"A":20.0,"B":"00052000"}]
```

i am trying to convert it to a data frame...

```
+-------+--------------+
|packQty|gtin          |
+-------+--------------+
|120.0  |0005236       |
|10.0   |0005200       | 
|12.0   |00042276      |
|20.0   |00052000      |
+-------+--------------+
```

i have created a schema as

```
 val schema=new StructType()
  .add("packQty",FloatType)
  .add("gtin", StringType)

val df =Seq(str).toDF("testQTY")
val df2=df.withColumn("jsonData",from_json($"testQTY",schema)).select("jsonData.*")
```

this is returning me a data frame with only one record...

```
+-------+--------------+
|packQty|gtin          |
+-------+--------------+
|120.0  |0005236|
+-------+--------------+
```

how to modify the schema so that i can get all the records

if it was a an array then i could have used explode() function to get the values, but i am getting this error.

```
cannot resolve 'explode(`gtins`)' due to data type mismatch: input to 
function explode should be array or map type, not string;;
```

this is how the column is populated

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| gtins                                                                                               
|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
|[{"packQty":120.0,"gtin":"000520"},{"packQty":10.0,”gtin":"0005200"}]
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That is not a string. I think it is trying to be an array but it is also not valid syntax in Scala. If you could update your question with how your data is actually stored, we could assist you better.

Comment: it is a string, its coming from a function with string as return type, i have updated the quetion with how the columns is populated

Comment: Than in that case you are missing some quotation marks. Did you mean to write 
```val str = "[{'A':120.0,'B':'0005236'},{'A':10.0,'B':'0005200'},
{'A':12.0,'B':'00042276'},{'A':20.0,'B':'00052000'}]"``` ? In that case you can define a case class and parse this to a Seq of that case class, which should be easy to convert to a DF

Comment: yes..."" what i am trying to do is to add a new column with the exploded items from this

Comment: @Srinivas & myself added the options for you, pick the best suitable for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your schema inside `ArrayType` i.e `ArrayType(new StructType().add("packQty",FloatType).add("gtin", StringType))` this will give you null values as schema column names are not matched with json data.

Change schema `ArrayType(new StructType().add("packQty",FloatType).add("gtin", StringType))` to `ArrayType(new StructType().add("A",FloatType).add("B", StringType))` & After parsing data rename the required columns.

Please check below code.

If column names are matched in both `schema` & `JSON` data.

```
scala> val json = Seq("""[{"A":120.0,"B":"0005236"},{"A":10.0,"B":"0005200"},{"A":12.0,"B":"00042276"},{"A":20.0,"B":"00052000"}]""").toDF("testQTY")
json: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [testQTY: string]

scala> val schema = ArrayType(StructType(StructField("A",DoubleType,true):: StructField("B",StringType,true) :: Nil))
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType = ArrayType(StructType(StructField(A,DoubleType,true), StructField(B,StringType,true)),true)

scala> json.withColumn("jsonData",from_json($"testQTY",schema)).select(explode($"jsonData").as("jsonData")).select($"jsonData.A".as("packQty"),$"jsonData.B".as("gtin")).show(false)
+-------+--------+
|packQty|gtin    |
+-------+--------+
|120.0  |0005236 |
|10.0   |0005200 |
|12.0   |00042276|
|20.0   |00052000|
+-------+--------+
```

If column names are not matched in both `schema` & `JSON` data.

```
scala> val json = Seq("""[{"A":120.0,"B":"0005236"},{"A":10.0,"B":"0005200"},{"A":12.0,"B":"00042276"},{"A":20.0,"B":"00052000"}]""").toDF("testQTY")
json: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [testQTY: string]

scala> val schema = ArrayType(StructType(StructField("packQty",DoubleType,true):: StructField("gtin",StringType,true) :: Nil)) // Column names are not matched with json & schema.
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType = ArrayType(StructType(StructField(packQty,DoubleType,true), StructField(gtin,StringType,true)),true)

scala> json.withColumn("jsonData",from_json($"testQTY",schema)).select(explode($"jsonData").as("jsonData")).select($"jsonData.*").show(false)
+-------+----+
|packQty|gtin|
+-------+----+
|null   |null|
|null   |null|
|null   |null|
|null   |null|
+-------+----+
```

Alternative way of parsing `json string` into DataFrame using `DataSet`

```
scala> val json = Seq("""[{"A":120.0,"B":"0005236"},{"A":10.0,"B":"0005200"},{"A":12.0,"B":"00042276"},{"A":20.0,"B":"00052000"}]""").toDS // Creating DataSet from json string.
json: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> val schema = StructType(StructField("A",DoubleType,true):: StructField("B",StringType,true) :: Nil) // Creating schema.
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(A,DoubleType,true), StructField(B,StringType,true))

scala> spark.read.schema(schema).json(json).select($"A".as("packQty"),$"B".as("gtin")).show(false)
+-------+--------+
|packQty|gtin    |
+-------+--------+
|120.0  |0005236 |
|10.0   |0005200 |
|12.0   |00042276|
|20.0   |00052000|
+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Specifying one more option -

```scala
 val data = """[{"A":120.0,"B":"0005236"},{"A":10.0,"B":"0005200"},{"A":12.0,"B":"00042276"},{"A":20.0,"B":"00052000"}]"""

 val df2 = Seq(data).toDF("gtins")
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()

    /**
      * +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |gtins                                                                                                   |
      * +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |[{"A":120.0,"B":"0005236"},{"A":10.0,"B":"0005200"},{"A":12.0,"B":"00042276"},{"A":20.0,"B":"00052000"}]|
      * +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- gtins: string (nullable = true)
      */

    df2.selectExpr("inline_outer(from_json(gtins, 'array<struct<A:double, B:string>>')) as (packQty, gtin)")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+--------+
      * |packQty|gtin    |
      * +-------+--------+
      * |120.0  |0005236 |
      * |10.0   |0005200 |
      * |12.0   |00042276|
      * |20.0   |00052000|
      * +-------+--------+
      */
```